# Discard revision in Hibernate Envers

Tags: hibernate-envers

I don't need to save revision in some cases for entity, but how to handle this way? I want to just skip creation of revision, already reviewed source codes, no chance.

If u try to make DB changes in custom EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl, for example, make calls in same transaction like that (in onPostInsert):

```
        PersistedProperty property = dao.findClass(PersistedProperty.class, "where propertyTemplate.id = ? and fileEntry.id = ?",
                propertyTemplate.getId(), f.getId());
        String v = convertObject2String(propertyTemplate, value);
        if (property == null) {
            property = new PersistedProperty(propertyTemplate, v, f);
        } else {
            property.setValue(v);
        }
        dao.merge(property);
```

Then u will get next exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
 at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1042)
 at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:587)
 at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1435)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:491)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3201)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2411)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
 at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
 at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
 at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
```

Problem is deep repeat of same instance of ActionQueue in AbstractSaveEventListener (line 318) and final modification of ActionQueue by inner transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation, there is a section called [Conditional Auditing](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_conditional_auditing) that discusses this.

The basic notion is you will need to override the Hibernate event listeners that Envers registers to handle triggering the auditing with your own custom implementations.

Your implementation will basically need to extend the Envers listeners and:

1. Check that the event is for the entity-type you're interested in skipping.
2. Check the modified state to see if only the condition that implies skipping occurred.
3. If you want to skip, simply don't delegate to the super implementation.

*If you are using the `ValidityAuditStrategy` instead of the `DefaultAuditStrategy`, I would highly recommend you avoid using conditional auditing for `INSERT` operations.*

*Using conditional auditing on `UPDATE` operations from what I can tell will work, but doing so on the original inserts will cause the `ADD` row never to be added and thus the `ValidityAuditStrategy` will assert on the first `UPDATE` you attempt to audit for that entity row.*

The goal in Hibernate 6 is to move beyond the need for users to manipulate the event listeners for conditional auditing and move toward a more JPA event listener annotation like approach.  For more details, see [HHH-11326](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11326).

Comment: How can I inject Spring beans inside custom EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl? it's really typical problem of any instance inside hibernate.

Comment: You could use a `ThreadLocal` variable you define before you call into your persistence layer or you could expose a singleton instance of your bean and access it that way.

Comment: When i create *`onPostInsert`* method in *`EnversPostInsertEventListener`* class; after the persist operation it called 3 times. First event is doing what i want and return. The second ones entity is *`DefaultRevisionEntity`* and its called super. Really dont understand what that is.

Comment: These callbacks are called for entities saved by Envers, so the code needs to be indempotent to only react to non-audit entities.